# SLF4J: Failed to load class at Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, iar

Using win10, Eclipse June 2020 C++ IDE, jdk-13.0.2, IAR plugin.
I have a project that contains several sub-projects and it doesn't compile using the command line (eclipsec.exe).

The running command

```
C:\eclipse\eclipsec.exe -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild  -no-indexer -data . -import lib1 -import libDsp -build PrjSystem/Debug
```

The result is that `libDsp` is not compiled.

The log's output:

```
Adding appender for logfile C:\work\.metadata\IAR-plugins.log
Opening 'LibDsp'.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Opening 'Lib1'.
Opening 'Lib2'.
...
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
```

Why LibDsp isn't created?

How to solve this `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".` issue? (The solution of pom.xml doesn't work because it's not Java IDE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project didn't compile because some of the files were "locked".
Example of a locked file:
`Error[Ms003]: could not open file "Components\folder\file.o" for writing`

After removing Eclipse `.metadata` folder or the specific file `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.safetable\org.eclipse.core.resources`, the files were freed.

`slf4j` is not related to this problem.